# Getting data from gridview row which is already retrived from sql db and pass it to the textbox outside gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I have table named Country in sql db, now i created the website in asp and i designed for grid view and i got values from sql througn grid view, i have three textbox  "CountryID" "Name" "CountryNotes" and ADD button in web page,  when i fill the textbox it will save to db and display it in gridview in same page itself using update panel,  now i want to edit the table in gridview,  so when i click edit button in each row of gridview it should pass the selected row values to texboxes which is in top of the page,  which mean that textbox is outside the gridview.  and i need to edit the content and update the data by click update button, which mean add button should change to update button

This is my HTML Page

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="script1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<div>

    <table align="center" style="width:50%;">
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style6">
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Country ID" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style7">
                <asp:TextBox ID="Text0" runat="server" Width="138px" ></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style8"></td>
            <td class="auto-style9">
                &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style1">
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Country Name" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style4">
                <asp:TextBox ID="Text1" runat="server" Width="137px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="auto-style5">
                &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style1">
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Country Notes" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style4">
                <asp:TextBox ID="Text2" runat="server" Width="136px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="auto-style5">
                &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add" BackColor="#990000" ForeColor="White" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
            </td>
            <td >
                <br />
                </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="auto-style5">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

    </table>

    <br />
    <br />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <Triggers>

                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="GridView1" EventName="PageIndexChanging" />

            </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" DataKeyNames="CountryID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">
        <Columns>







            <asp:BoundField DataField="CountryID" HeaderText="CountryID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CountryID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CountryNotes" HeaderText="CountryNotes" SortExpression="CountryNotes" />
            <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="EditRow" />

                 <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="true"/>


        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <RowStyle ForeColor="#000066" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#007DBB" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#00547E" />
    </asp:GridView>
        </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ATSConnectionString %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Country1] WHERE [CountryID] = @original_CountryID AND [Name] = @original_Name AND [CountryNotes] = @original_CountryNotes" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Country1] ([CountryID], [Name], [CountryNotes]) VALUES (@CountryID, @Name, @CountryNotes)" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Country1]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Country1] SET [Name] = @Name, [CountryNotes] = @CountryNotes WHERE [CountryID] = @original_CountryID AND [Name] = @original_Name AND [CountryNotes] = @original_CountryNotes" ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_CountryID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_CountryNotes" Type="String" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="CountryID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="CountryNotes" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="CountryNotes" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_CountryID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_CountryNotes" Type="String" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

</div>
</form>
```

This is my C# coding

```
public partial class atc : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    SqlConnection con;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

    }


    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=RYI-SYS-004;Initial Catalog=ATS;Integrated Security=True");
        cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Country1 (CountryID,Name,CountryNotes) values(@CountryID,@Name, @CountryNotes)", con);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CountryID", Text0.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Text1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CountryNotes", Text2.Text);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            Text0.Text = "";
            Text1.Text = "";
            Text2.Text = "";
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

    }

}
```

this is what my existing output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfJXc.png)

could anyone solve this problem!!

Comment: Text0.Text = GridView1.Rows[ROW_NUM][COL_NUM],Text; Note that both rows and columns are zero-inexed, btw so the first is 0, 2nd is 1, etc.

Comment: i am sorry, i dont know where to insert those coding which you commented, actually i didnt tried the edit event codes yet so if knew it could specify it correctly @Shannon Holsinger

Answer (score 1):

```
Note - there are a few changes you;ll want to make to this code. The example I'm giving you is not meant to be optimized or generalized - it's designed to answer your specific question while changing as little of your original code as possible. There may be other errors.  

public partial class atc : System.Web.UI.Page
{

SqlConnection con;
SqlCommand cmd;
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

}


protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=RYI-SYS-004;Initial Catalog=ATS;Integrated Security=True");
    cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Country1 (CountryID,Name,CountryNotes) values(@CountryID,@Name, @CountryNotes)", con);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CountryID", Text0.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Text1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CountryNotes", Text2.Text);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        Text0.Text = GridView1[ROW_NUM][COL_NUM].Text;
        Text1.Text = GridView1[ROW_NUM][COL_NUM].Text;
        Text2.Text = GridView1[ROW_NUM][COL_NUM].Text;
       // GridView1.DataBind();
    }

}

}
```

You need to enter the appropriate values for each ROW_NUM and COL_NUM above to make this work, like GridView1[0][0] or Gridview1[searchRow][4] where searchRow is an int.